# MySQL Syntax Error in table creation statement

Tags: mysql

This question is very straight forward. I have this MySQL error that I haven't been able to figure out, and I need some help finding it.

The full error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '**release date NOT NULL, downloads INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', f**' at line 6

The SQLStatement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sdm_downloads
    (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        project INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        release date NOT NULL,
        downloads INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        filename varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        filesize varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    )
```

Thanks in advance for any, and all help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've removed the irrelevant PHP tag; you should use tags to describe your question, not your project ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `release` with backticks

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sdm_downloads
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    project INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `release` date NOT NULL,
    downloads INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    filename varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    filesize varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69dce)

Comment: Isn't also adding a string `'0'` as a default value for an int bad?

Comment: @user2336873 Also, using reserved words for columns, tables or downright anything in databases is BAD. Change the column name, it will save you so much trouble later on. Really, please.